# validacion campo presente en update agregando una condición - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando hacer una validacion para un campo obligatorio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando voy a crear el registro, todo bien, me indica que es obligatorio. pero al momento de hacer el update, esta validacion no pasa.

Para poner en contexto, valido que Vehiculo tenga una bodega , tanto al crear como actualizar.

la validacion no pasa particularmente por que este campo en cuestion (bodega_id), cuando se elimina, tiene un borrado logico, por lo que su id continua estando en el registro, solo que no se ve en el formulario (imagen2).
Entonces, queria ver como hago que esta validacion exista en el update pero conla condicion de que su bodega_id tenga un is_active = 0

```
 validates :depot_id, presence: true, numericality: true, on: :create
  validates :depot_id, presence: true, numericality: true, on: :update if ....
```

acá desconozco como  formular este if, para darle el bodega_id donde is_active = 0.
si esto se cumpliese, debiera pedirme una bodega (bodega no puede estar en blanco.)

Agradezco de antemano cualquier comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una lambda

`validates :depot_id, presence: true, numericality: true, on: :update if: -> { condicion }`

O con método:

```
validates :description, presence: true, if: :some_validation_check

def some_validation_check
   condicion
end
```

Comment: lo resolví con algo similar. gracias @damuz91

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar una lambda para la cláusula if: y hacer una condición.

```
validates :depot_id, presence: true, numericality: true, on: :update if: -> { is_active = 0 }
```